# vb.net html input placeholder

Tags: vb.net

HTML Code

```
<input placeholder="0000000000" type="text" name="msisdn" id="msisdn">
```

i've tried innertext by this code :

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("msisdn").InnerText = TextBox1.Text
```

but it change the placeholder value not the inner text of textbox
i want to change the exact text value of textbox not the placeholder value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("msisdn").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `.value` property.

`innerText` is for content; `<input>` elements don't have content.

Comment: so what i have to do ?

Comment: @Karim : Switch `.InnerText` to `.Value`.

Comment: @KarimMamdouh: These are properties of HTML DOM elements; they're the same regardless of language.

Comment: @Karim : Sorry. I know that you're using VB.NET, my intentions were for you to change your VB.NET code. **Though** you're right that `.Value` doesn't exists in VB.NET, I was mistaken. You have to use `.GetAttribute("value")`.

Comment: @SLaks : `.Value` is not. I forgot that.

Comment: it give me "false" as a value !